Problema Gate Laravel con Livewire
Tengo el siguiente Gate:
class PrizePolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
    */
    public function create(User $user, Raffle $raffle): bool {
        return $user->id === $raffle->user_id;
    }
}

Y en Livewire tengo:
public function save()
{
    $this->authorize('create', $this->raffle);
}

Lo que busco es que solamente puedan crear premios (Prize) si el usuario en cuestión es el propietario de la rifa (Raffle)
Sin embargo sin importar como acomode el parámetro me retorna error 403 | This action is unauthorized. Ya he intentado encerrarlo en un array, dejarlo como $this->raffle->id pero nada me ha funcionado.
Agradezco me puedan orientar/explicar el por que no me está funcionando este Gate; de antemano muchas gracias.
